# When does the comment block with schema information for the model get updated by rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In some Rails model definitions, there is a comment block at the top that contains the schema information.

```
# == Schema Information                                   
# Schema version: 20090122060318                          
#                                                         
# Table name: table_name
#                                                         
#  id            :integer(4)      not null, primary key   
...
```

When does this get updated?  Is it only generated once, when you use the generator script to create the model?  Is there a way to update this block when migrations are performed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Seems like output of the [annotate_models](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) plugin. Just install it and run `annotate` in your rails root and the schema information will update automatically. Ideally, run it after each migration.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the **annotate-models** gem. It's a bit less intrusive as there's no plugin needed.

Usage:

```
% gem install annotate
% annotate
Annotated Product, User, Role
```